# uialertview textfield invisible ios 10.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

I have UIAlertView with text field.

```
UIAlertView *corrmsg=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Enter Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",@"Forgot Password", nil];
    corrmsg.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [corrmsg show];
    [corrmsg release];
```

On iPad iOS 10.1.1 text field become invisible, no cursor, no box, although keyboard comes up and works fine, if you just blindly type in.

[image]

Anybody has a clue what how to fix that?

Switched to UIAlertController but that did not help:(

```
        UIAlertController *alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Enter Password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Enter Password", @"Password");
     }];

    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self okBttn:alertController.textFields.firstObject.text];
    }]];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self forgotPasswordBttn];
    }]];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self cancelBttn];
    }]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [alertController release];
```

UPDATE: elevating deployment targets >9.0 fixed UIAlertController!

Comment: `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for a while now. Use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, switched to UIAlertController - same story, any other thoughts?

Comment: elevating depl traget to >9.0 fixed UIAlertController

Comment: Are you using simulator or a device?

Comment: I use iPad 4th gen iOS 10.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Where r u configure the `UITextField`? 
Try smthn like this:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(@"")
                                                  message:@"Enter Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
}
```

Comment: Since i use myAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput; i do not need to, but thank you for suggestion. I could try [myAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; etc instead, However, as rmaddy pointed out it was deprecated, I am switching to UIAlertController to avoid any future unpredictability.

Comment: 1) `UIAlertView` is deprecated. 2) Don't create your own `UITextField` and add it to the alert. `UIAlertView` already has support for adding text fields. 3) Are you really still using MRC instead of ARC?

Comment: Right you are, rmaddy, i am not going to be adding textview on top of the one that is there already, I can access it and edit. It is an old app and yes it is MRC. Need to switch it to ARC and elevate its deployment target too.